# How to stop browser from encoding <, >, and & when reading a TXT file iframe in Web page?

Tags: javascript, iframe, text, innerhtml, pre

I have noticed that browsers will encode left bracket <, right bracket >, and ampersand & into their respective codes (&lt;/&gt;/&amp;) when reading the innerHTML of a **TXT**-file source iframe. How do I stop this from happening? The innerHTML will also be wrapped in a <pre> tag as well.

For example, suppose I have the following inside a **TXT** (not HTML) file:

```
<div>
    Hello world! I love M&M's candy.
</div>
```

The following iframe:

```
<iframe id="MyIframe" src="/hello.txt"></iframe>
```

And the following JavaScript:

```
var MyIframe = document.getElementById('MyIframe');
alert(MyIframe.contentWindow.document.innerHTML);
```

The alert dialog box will pop up with the following:

```
<pre>
    &lt;div&gt;Hello world! I love M&amp;M's candy.&lt;/div&gt;
</pre>
```

How do I stop JavaScript from doing this with the content of the **TXT** file? I just want the raw, un-encoded content of the file.

I cannot use XMLHTTPRequest.

Comment: you can use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`. When you check the network-log, what Content-Type does the server send with the text-file?

Comment: @Thomas "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of retrieving `.innerHTML`, retrieve `.textContent`. This should return only the human-readable text in an element tree, in a human-readable form. You can try it out on this page by Inspect-ing one of your HTML samples in your question, and writing `$0.textContent` in the developer console.

Answer (score 1):

The browser converts your text file into HTML. If you inspect the DOM of https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt, you'll see that it's HTML, not just a plain text file when it renders it.

As others have suggested, you can just retrieve `MyIframe.contentWindow.document.textContent` which will decode any HTML special  characters (now that you know the browser automatically encodes it).

[image]